# Установить максимальную глубину поиска QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt

Как можно установить максимальную глубину поиска в QT/C++, используя QDirIterator?

Так происходит итерация по заданной директории:

```
QDir dir;
QDirIterator it(dir.path(), QDirIterator::Subdirectories);    
QFileInfoList info_list;

while (it.hasNext()) {
    QFile f(it.next());
    QFileInfo info(f);
}
```

Comment: Всмысле как? Установить количество итараций.

Comment: Не количество выводимых файлов, а то насколько далеко искать по подпапкам

Comment: Тогда рекурсия вам в помощь - счётчик только не забывайте передавать